# The client with object id does not have authorization to perform action taggedTrafficConsumers/validate

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault

When using Azure Key Vault management REST API or cmdlet `Add-AzureRmKeyVaultNetworkRule` to allow a virtual network to access a key vault, I get the following error:

```
The client '{guid}' with object id '{guid}' does not have authorization to perform
action 'microsoft.network/virtualnetworks/taggedTrafficConsumers/validate/action'
over scope '/subscriptions/{guid}/resourcegroups/{resource-group}/providers/microsoft.network/virtualnetworks/{vnet-name}/taggedTrafficConsumers/Microsoft.KeyVault'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your subscription is not giving `Microsoft.KeyVault` resource provider permission to access `Microsoft.Network` resources. The fix is to register your subscription to `Microsoft.KeyVault` again:

```
Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.KeyVault
```

This will add required permissions for `Microsoft.KeyVault` and `Microsoft.Network` integrations, including the ability to limit access to a given Virtual Network.

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services

Comment: Note that it's the subscription with the vnet where you need to register/re-registeer the 'Microsoft.KeyVault' resource provider.

Comment: Just an update for the modern Az PowerShell Module it is:

`Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.KeyVault`

and for users of Azure CLI it is: `az provider register --namespace Microsoft.KeyVault`

Answer (score 0):

This are the steps required to solve it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types#azure-portal

You just need to register the resource provider in the subscription, this doesn't only happens with Key Vault, my issue was with Sql Server as well :)

So I leave this answer here in case someone else needs it

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a bug/limitation in both the Azure Portal and Azure CLI. We ran into this when trying to allow a subnet of a VNET in subscription X to access a storage account in subscription Y.

For us, the workaround was to look-up the name of the service principal that was mentioned in the error in our Azure AD directory using the "Search your tenant" box on the "Overview" tab of the directory (NOT the subscription but the Azure AD directory for the tenant). The name of the SP turned out to be "Storage Resource Provider" (yours may be different, so that's why you need to look it up in Azure AD), so we granted that SP "Owner" role (temporarily) in the other subscription. Then provisioning worked!

There should be a finer-grained set of permissions you need to grant than just "Owner" but when we granted just the "validate" permission, we got a new error:

> Failed to save firewall and virtual network settings for storage account 'XXX'. Error: An operation is currently performing on this storage account that requires exclusive access.

Answer (score 0):

Also experienced this error when adding a vnet to a storage-account in another subscription.

Fixed by adding a storage-account to the subscription using the portal. Then the vnet could be added to the storage-account.

Note: the result is the same as @fernacolo does with a powershell command.